# yii2, grid view, add class to 1 row (total rows- 10)

Tags: gridview, yii2

How can i add class to 1 row total rows- 10 in grid view yii2?.

Comment: Where exactly? Can you add screenshot with some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for applying class to a first row in your gridview, then you can use `rowOptions` property of `gridview` as follows, I am applying class `even` to first row which can be accessed by `index=0`. You can change `index` as per your requirement.

```
'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
                                    if ($index == 0) {
                                        return ['class' =>'even'];
                                    }
                                }
```